# View all comments from a facebook page, on my own site

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments, feed

Is there in anyway i can make a FB:Comments or something else, which shows me the comments that i give people, and the comments people are leaving, at my page on Facebook ?

In basic.. i just wanna see everything thats written on the wall/news feed on my page..

Anyone knows how this is possible or if it is possible ??

Comment: By "like" page - do you mean simply a facebook page that you are administrating?

Comment: Yes, have no idea what else i should call it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create an application that has the `manage_pages` permission.   With this permission, you'll be able to extract all the posts from your page and then display them however you see fit.
For more information on creating applications - you can [read here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/)
For information about permissions on facebook - you can [read here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: Do i really need an application for that ?

Comment: try the Facebook documentation of social plugins, maybe that will suit you better...

Comment: Ty... Ill see if I can find something there